# using a modal to make a dynamic form angular

Tags: angular, forms, dynamic, modal-dialog

I am somewhat new to angular, but I am trying to create a dynamic form that will create something in my db that has fields that change depending on a dropdown selector at the top of the same modal. I have done some research but all I am finding is help with full module dynamic forms and not the modal. Is this possible? And if so what would be a great place to start this research?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this type of feature is a very important part of Angular.

For a good demonstration of this, [**see this example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qokxpq), which changes the options of which "States" you can select based on the country you select.

The important parts are the template, which defines the look of the page and the placeholders for the data...

```
<label>Country:</label> 
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedCountry.id" (change)="onSelect($event.target.value)">
  <option value="0">--Select--</option>
  <option *ngFor="let country of countries" value= {{country.id}}>{{country.name}}</option>
</select>

<br/><br/>

<div>
<label>State:</label>
<select>
  <option value="0">--Select--</option>
  <option *ngFor="let state of states " value= {{state.id}}>{{state.name}}</option>
</select>
</div>
```

...and the controller, which defines **what** data should be shown. As you make click in the template, the data in the controller is manipulated

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  name = 'Angular 5';

  selectedCountry: Country = new Country(2, 'Brazil');
  countries: Country[];
  states: State[];

  constructor(private selectService: SelectService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.countries = this.selectService.getCountries();
    this.onSelect(this.selectedCountry.id);
  }

  onSelect(countryid) {
    this.states = this.selectService.getStates().filter((item) => item.countryid == countryid);
  }
}
```